# Persistent Shadow Copy in XP SP2?

Tags: windows-xp, copy, shadow, volume-shadow-service

I'm wondering if XP supports persistent shadow copying like Windows Vista/7 do. I read the wikipedia article about Shadow Copy and it had this paragraph (emphasis mine):

> **The creation of persistent snapshots (multiple snapshots which remain
>   available across reboots until
>   specifically deleted from the system)
>   has been added in Windows Server
>   2003**, allowing up to 512 snapshots
>   to exist simultaneously for the same
>   volume. In Windows Server 2003, VSS is
>   therefore used to create incremental
>   periodic snapshots of data or deltas
>   (differences) of changed files over
>   time. A maximum of 64 snapshots are
>   stored on the server and accessible by
>   clients or on the same server through
>   network shares. This feature is known
>   as Shadow copies for Shared Folders
>   and is designed for a client-server
>   model. The Shadow copies for Shared
>   Folders client is required to be
>   installed on Windows 2000 and Windows
>   XP RTM and SP1. A copy of this client
>   for 32-bit Windows platforms is
>   available on the server or
>   downloadable from Microsoft. **It is
>   built into the OS beginning with
>   Windows XP SP2**.

I interpreted this as XP having the ability to create persistent Shadow Copies, or partial copies of a file that exist even when the network connection is broken.

If you can shed some light on the supported functionality I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

XP does not support persistent Shadow Copies, so you must supply a script/app to call back if you use the sample client, or create the shadow copy and work with it in the same process in case you use the API.